# How to know for sure if requests.get has timed out?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In this line of code:

```
request = requests.get(url, verify=False, headers=headers, proxies=proxy, timeout=15)
```

How do I know that `timeout=15` has been triggered so I can send a message that `url` did not send any data in 15 seconds?

Comment: Please accept one of the answers if they answered the question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a response is not received from the server at all within the given time, then an exception `requests.exceptions.Timeout` is thrown, as per [Exa's link](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts) from the other answer.

To test if this occurred we can use a `try, except` block to detect it and act accordingly, rather than just letting our program crash.

Expanding on the demonstration used in the docs:

```py
import requests

try:
    requests.get('https://github.com/', timeout=0.001)
except requests.exceptions.Timeout as e:
    # code to run if we didn't get a reply
    print("Request timed out!\nDetails:", e)
else:
    # code to run if we did get a response, and only if we did.
    print(r.headers)
```

Just substitute your url and timeout where appropriate.

Comment: If this answered your question please mark it as as such!

Answer (score 1):

An exception will be thrown. See [this](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#timeouts) for more info.

Comment: Thank you! Somehow I skipped it and went straight down to the Timeouts section :(